# How to deploy a single HTML file on Tomcat 6

Tags: html, tomcat, deployment

I have an HTML file named "testUrBuddy.html". I want to run this file on my local host. I have a Tomcat 6 server installed. When I run the server I get these logs:

```
Jul 31, 2014 5:40:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin; ...
Jul 31, 2014 5:40:22 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080 Jul 31, 2014 5:40:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization processed in 600 ms
Jul 31, 2014 5:40:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start INFO: Starting service Catalina 
Jul 31, 2014 5:40:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.37 
Jul 31, 2014 5:40:22 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080 
Jul 31, 2014 5:40:22 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Jul 31, 2014 5:40:22 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=1/16 config=null Jul 31, 2014 5:40:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in 390 ms
```

This means my server is running. I put my testUrBuddy.html file in the webapps\ROOT folder. After running the server, when I type `http://localhost:8080/testUrBuddy.html` on the URL I am getting this error :

```
HTTP Status 404 - /testUrBuddy.html     description The requested resource is not available.
```

Do i have change something in web.xml or somewhere else?.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the file into a web project. The project needs at least a WEB-INF folder including a web.xml file. If you are using Eclipse, do this:

1. Click "New"
2. Select "Other"
3. Select "Dynamic Web Project"
4. Follow the instructions and mark the checkbox "create deployment descriptor" (web.xml).
5. Put the HTML file into the "webapps" folder.
6. Export it as a war file.